# Cargar datos desde MYSQL hacia Formulario PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy elaborando un formulario para cargar datos desde una base de datos `MYSQl` son los mismos datos que ingrese, solo que quiero que en este formulario se puedan editar, el código que tengo es:

```
 <?php
// 1) Conexión

if ($conexión = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "clave")){
echo "<p>MySQL le ha dado permiso a PHP para ejecutar consultas con ese usuario</p>";

// 2) Preparar la orden SQL

$consulta= "SELECT*FROM mensajes";

// 3) Ejecutar la orden y obtener datos

mysql_select_db("cursos");
$datos= mysql_query ($consulta);

// 4) Ir Imprimiendo las filas resultantes

while ($fila =mysql_fetch_array($datos)){
echo "<p">;
echo $fila ["id"];
echo "-"; // un separador
echo $fila["nombre"];
echo "-"; // un separador
echo $fila ["email"];
echo "-"; // un separador
echo $fila["mensaje"];
echo "</p>";
}

}else{
echo "MySQL no conoce ese usuario y password";
}
?>
```

Esto funciona pero no solo quiero que me los muestre(`echo`), lo que quiero es inyectar los datos al formulario `HTML`**(nombre,email, etc)**, con el propósito de editar la información previamente ingresada, (sin usar `javascript`)

```
<!-- formulario de contacto para el ingreso de datos -->



<form action="envia.php" method="post" class="form-consulta"> 
        <label>Nombre y apellido: <span>*</span>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y apellido" class="campo-form" required>
        </label>

        <label>Email: <span>*</span>
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="campo-form" required>
        </label>

        <label>Consulta:
            <textarea name="consulta" class="campo-form"></textarea>
        </label>

        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn-form">
    </form>

<!-- formulario -->
```

He encontrado una manera poco convencional con `javascript` y me funciona pero quiero hacerlo, mas adecuado,para evitar que los bloqueadores de `script` me cancelen la función, :D acepto sus comentarios, ayudas y sugerencias, saludos a todos

Comment: En primer lugar, no uses `mysql`, está obsoleto, en vez de eso usa `mysqli`. Por otro lado, no acabo de entender la pregunta, qué quieres hacer exactamente?

Comment: La pregunta es sobre Desarrollo web especificamente, php, mysql , y html y esta bien explicado, un desarrollador seguramente lo entenderá, gracias por la sugerencia sobre mysql investigare si cambiaron el nombre en la versión 8 que sacaron recientemente, lo tomare en cuenta y de nuevo gracias!

Comment: Vaya investigue, creo que tu refieres a la forma de conectarse, mysql, mysqli y PDO, tienes razón mysqli es orientada a objetos y es el metodo mas reciente, pero la base aun se llama mysql quizá por eso sonó confuso para ti, tratare de usar mas mysqli gracias por el consejo

Comment: deberías dejar de usar el driver mysql ya que es obsoleto e inseguro en su lugar mysqli o mejor aun PDO

Comment: ya lo menciono arriba alex55132, pero gracias!

Comment: La consulta no se entiende del todo bien, a que se refiere con "inyectar"?

Comment: Dios mío, pues pinta el formulario y pon los valores con PHP, haciendo echo mismamente, ¿no?

Answer (score 1):

Mete el `form` en el mismo PHP y usa las variables que ya tienes definidas

```
echo"<textarea name="consulta" class="campo-form">".$fila["mensaje"]."</textarea>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente.

```
<!-- formulario de contacto para el ingreso de datos -->
<?php 
$strNombre = $fila["nombre"];
$strEmail = $fila ["email"];
$strMensaje = $fila["mensaje"];

$txtNombre = '<input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre y apellido" class="campo-form" value="@strNombre" required>';
$txtEmail = '<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="campo-form" value="@strEmail" required>';
$txtConsulta = '<textarea name="consulta" class="campo-form">@strMensaje</textarea>';

$txtNombre = str_replace("@strNombre",$strNombre,$txtNombre);
$txtEmail = str_replace("@strEmail",$strEmail,$txtEmail);
$txtConsulta = str_replace("@strMensaje",$strMensaje,$txtConsulta);
?>
<form action="envia.php" method="post" class="form-consulta"> 
   <label>Nombre y apellido: <span>*</span>
      <?php echo $txtNombre; ?>
   </label>

   <label>Email: <span>*</span>
      <?php echo $txtEmail; ?>
   </label>

   <label>Consulta:
      <?php echo $txtConsulta; ?>
   </label>

   <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn-form">
</form>
<!-- formulario -->
```